# PHP вывод формы

Tags: php, html, form

Есть форма и `php` скрипт её вывода.

Форма

```html
<div class="cartWrap__order">
                        <div class="white-cart">
                            <div class="h1">Оформление заказа:</div>
                            <form method='POST' class="cart__form" id="orderCartForm" action="send.php">
                                <input type="hidden" name="formid" value="orderForm">
                                <input type="hidden" name="evoShop_items_json" class="evoShop_items_json" value=''/>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-4">
                                        <div class="cart__columnTitle">Личные данные</div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="name">Ваше имя</label>
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="name" value="">
                                            <div class="form-control-feedback"></div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="phone">Ваш телефон</label>
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control phone-mask" name="phone" id="phone" value="">
                                            <div class="form-control-feedback"></div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group ">
                                            <label for="dopphone">Дополнительный телефон</label>
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control phone-mask" name="dopphone" id="dopphone" value="">
                                            <div class="form-control-feedback"></div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="col-md-4">
                                        <div class="cart__columnTitle">Доставка</div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="delivery">Метод доставки</label>
                                            <select class="form-control js-select" name="delivery" id="delivery">
                                                <option value="Курьер">Курьером</option>
                                                <option value="Самовывоз">Самовывоз</option>
                                            </select>
                                            <div class="form-control-feedback"></div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group hidden js-if-delivery">
                                            <label for="delivery_city">Город для доставки</label>
                                            <select class="form-control js-select" name="delivery_city" id="delivery_city">
                                                <option value="РБ">Не Минск (укажите в адресе)</option>
                                                <option value="Минск">Минск</option>
                                            </select>
                                            <div class="form-control-feedback"></div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group hidden js-if-delivery" id="for_address">
                                            <label for="address">Адрес</label>
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="address" id="address" value="">
                                            <div class="form-control-feedback"></div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="message">Комментарий к заказу</label>
                                            <textarea class="form-control" name="message" id="message" rows="3"></textarea>
                                        </div>  

                                    </div>

                                    <div class="col-md-4">
                                        <div class="cart__columnTitle">Оплата</div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="payment">Метод оплаты</label>
                                            <select class="form-control js-select" name="payment" id="payment">
                                                <option value="Наличными">Наличными при получении</option>
                                                <option value="Безналичными">Безналичными при получении</option>
                                                <option value="webpay">WebPay</option>
                                            </select>
                                            <div class="form-control-feedback"></div>
                                        </div>
                                        <br>
                                        <div class="evoShop_cart">
                                            <div class="total-price" style="text-align:left">Итого: <b><span class="evoShop_total"></span></b></div>    
                                            <div class="total-price js-shipping-row" style="text-align:left">Доставка: <b><span class="evoShop_shipping"></span></b></div>  
                                            <!--
                                            <div class="total-price js-discount-row" style="text-align:left">Скидка: <b><span class="evoShop_discount"></span></b></div>    -->
                                            <div class="total-price" style="text-align:left">К оплате: <b><span class="evoShop_grandTotal"></span></b></div>    
                                        </div>  
                                        <button type="submit" class="btn evoShop_submit">Оформить заказ</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </form>  
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Скрипт

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
$tel = $_POST['phone'];
$dop_tel = $_POST['dopphone']
$delivery = $_POST['delivery']
$city = $_POST['delivery_city']
$addres = $_POST['address']
$comment = $_POST['message']
$payment = $_POST['payment']
echo($name, $tel, $dop_tel, $delivery, $city, $addres, $comment, $payment)
?>
```

После нажатия на кнопку все валится с ошибкой
`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$delivery' (T_VARIABLE) in /storage/ssd3/787/15965787/public_html/send.php on line 5`

Очевидно, что я неправильно присваиваю значение переменной из выпадающего списка. Как это сделать правильно?

Comment: Может быть надо ставить точку с запятой? $dop_tel = $_POST['dopphone']; $delivery = $_POST['delivery']; и т.д.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Исправление вашей ошибки:

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
$tel = $_POST['phone'];
$dop_tel = $_POST['dopphone'];
$delivery = $_POST['delivery'];
$city = $_POST['delivery_city'];
$addres = $_POST['address'];
$comment = $_POST['message'];
$payment = $_POST['payment'];
echo $name. " ". $tel. " ". $dop_tel. " ". $delivery. " ". $city. " ". $addres. " ". $comment. " ". $payment ;
?>
```

Comment: @ClarkDevlin исправил.